# How can I style a list item to contain images without any gaps between them?

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to style a set of images contained within an unordered list so that:

- The `<ul>` occupies the full width of the containing element
- Each `<li>` occupies 25% of the width of the `<ul>`
- The images contained in the `<li>`scale proportionately as the screen is resized
- The 8 total images arrange in two stacked rows of 4 images each
- There are no gaps, either vertically or horizontally, between the images

I can accomplish the first four objectives in the list above, but can't seem to lose the gap between the first and second row of images.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="container">  
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://davidangerer.com/i/sample.jpg" alt="Image Description" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the (post-reset) CSS:

```
.container { 
    width: 90%
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 6em auto;
}
.container ul {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}
.container img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;    /* fixes a bug in ie8 */
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set `display:block;` on the images and the `li`s to avoid that ugly inline margin between them. Check out this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzgMX/)

```
.container img { 
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;    /* fixes a bug in ie8 */
}

.container ul li{ display:block; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Yotam. Looks like adding `vertical-align: top;` to the CSS governing the `<img>` also closes the gap.

Comment: Yep there are a few ways to do this.. I personally think that when working with images like this it's better to add `display:block`. glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

image are inline-boxes and stands on baseline (defaut value : `vertical-align:baseline;`). This explains the gap underneath. you can either fix it like:

```
.container img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;    /* fixes a bug in ie8 */
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

or

```
.container img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;    /* fixes a bug in ie8 */
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

or make your inline-boxe into a block-boxe

```
.container img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;    /* fixes a bug in ie8 */
    display:block;;
}
```